# pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed

Tags: python, pyvisa

I am trying to automate test-equipment with Python.
My power supply is a kikusui and the multimeter is an Agilent 34401A.
The problem I'm having is in this line:

```
vMeasured = float ( dmm . query ( ':MEASure:VOLTage:DC?' ) )
```

The console returns this message:

```
pyvisa.errors.VisaIOError: VI_ERROR_TMO (-1073807339): Timeout expired before operation completed.
```

Could you help me? I think that the problem is in query order, but before, when I do a `DMM.query("*IDN?")` it returns a correct string.
In this code I only try to read the voltage from the power supply.

```py
import pyvisa

rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
rm.list_resources()
print("Recursos detectados\n{}\n".format(rm.list_resources()))

PS = rm.open_resource('ASRL3::INSTR')
DMM = rm.open_resource('ASRL11::INSTR')

print('FA:',PS.query("*IDN?"))
print('DMM:',DMM.query("*IDN?"))

PS.write('OUTPut:COUPling DC')
PS.write('OUTPut OFF')
PS.write('VOLTage:OFFSet 5')
PS.write('CURRent:OFFSet 1')
PS.write('OUTPut ON')

DMM.timeout = 2000
Medida_V = float(DMM.query("MEASure:VOLTage:DC?"))
print('Medida_V:',Medida_V)
```

I'm trying to read the Voltage measure in my PC with my python script using `pyvisa`